# Combine tags [slim] and [slimframework]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim) and [slimframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slimframework) absolutely, positively refer to the exact same "RESTful micro framework for PHP 5 inspired by Sinatra."

It would seem that [slimframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slimframework) is the lesser-used one (only 11 followers and 51 questions), so I propose that we merge that into [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim).

Comment: I agree. I'm often looking questions related to Slim and I think it would be better if we had only one tag. Keep only [tag:slim] seems the best choice for me too.

Comment: Seems like no one else is paying attention :(

Comment: As a regular follower of slim tag I agree on this one.

Comment: Well then, everyone, [upvote the synonym suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/slim/synonyms)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an open vote to make [slimframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slimframework) be a synonym of [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim). If you have enough reputation (an answer score of at least 5 in that tag), simply go to the latter's page and upvote the suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slim/synonyms