# Should I ask reviewers to upvote a synonym suggestion...in my edit summary?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, tag-synonym-process, edit-summary

I've been pushing to get [this synonym suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slim/synonyms) approved for months now, ever since I opened [this question in September](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305510/combine-tags-slim-and-slimframework).

For whatever reason, it seems like my suggestion hasn't caught on or gotten enough exposure.  However it's really, really obvious that [`slimframework`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slimframework/info) is a redundant tag, and whoever created it didn't bother to look at the [description for the canonical tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slim/info).  The two tags are 100%, without a doubt, referring to the exact same thing.

So, I've tried to subtly nudge the suggestion forward by editing questions with the redundant tag, and replacing it with the canonical tag (and [version-specific tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/slim-3/info), when appropriate).  **In my edit summaries**, I've been linking to the synonym suggestion in the hopes that it will get upvoted and approved.  Is this useful?

Not that I mind the extra reputation for fixing these questions, but it would be a lot more efficient for the synonym to just be approved already, and all questions with the tag to be bulk re-tagged.  A lot of SO newbies are using the non-canonical tag (and *only* the non-canonical tag), thus hurting their chances of getting useful help from people who may only be subscribed to the canonical tag.

Comment: Create a meta-post tagged [meta-tag:synonym-request].  That will give the synonym meta attention where hopefully enough people will be able to approve it.  You should probably read the tag wiki for how to properly use the meta tag.

Comment: Ah, good call.  My original meta-post had the `retag-request` tag, but not `synonym-request`.

Comment: See [How to gather support for tag synonyms?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312430) ... Ironically that question itself did not get enough support.